# replacing function in stylus

Tags: javascript, stylus

I have Stylus file with that code:

```
body
  background url('/templates/main/img/sprites/ico-soc.png') 100px 100px no-repeat
```

I need function(mixin) `background` which will remove '/templates/main/' from the image's reference

```
body
      background url('img/sprites/ico-soc.png') 100px 100px no-repeat
```

Please help me) I think maybe I went in the wrong direction, and there is a simple way to solve the problem.  note that I need the function. Don't offer to create a variable for the directory!

---

**That's what I'm doing**

I made function

```
background()
  background arguments
```

then I tried to solve the problem in two ways
1) I tried to find a replacement function. but failed. 
Then i tried to use the decision of the documentation (function replace). But it does not fit my case.
http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#add-propertyname-expr

2) I wrote my function on js through the function use(path) (http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#usepath).
But I had the problem the value coming into js function is not correct. There are extra spaces.

style.styl

```
use("add.js")

background()
  background arguments

body
  background url('img/sprites/ico-soc.png') 100px 100px no-repeat
```

add.js

```
    var plugin = function(){
    return function(style){
        style.define('add', function(a) {
            console.log(typeof a);
            console.log(a);
        });
    };
};
module.exports = plugin;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `url` function and check that it's called from `background`, using `current-property`. For example:

```
url(str)
  if current-property && current-property[0] == 'background'
    str = replace('/templates/main/', '', str)

  return unquote('url(' + str + ')')

body
  background: url('/templates/main/img/sprites/ico-soc.png') 100px 100px no-repeat
```

Compiles to:

```
body {
  background: url(img/sprites/ico-soc.png) 100px 100px no-repeat;
}
```